# Is this expression of the Riemann zeta function as a Mellin transform true for $\Im\{s\}\neq 0$?

Tags: laplace-transform, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, dirac-delta, mellin-transform

For sure, we can write 
\begin{align}
\zeta(s)&=\int_0^\infty \sum_{n\geq 1}\delta\big(\log \frac{x}{n}\big)x^{-s-1}dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty \sum_{n\geq 1}\delta(x-n)x^{-s}dx \nonumber \\
&=\sum_{n\geq 1}n^{-s}\quad \forall s | \Re\{s\}>1 \nonumber \\
\end{align}
where $\delta$ is Dirac's delta.

In an answer by reuns [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277266/what-is-the-formula-for-fourier-transform-or-mellin-transform-of-riemann-zeta?rq=1), I find that we add a regularization term for $0<\Re\{s\}<1$ :
$$\zeta(s)=\int_0^\infty \Big(-x+\sum_{n\geq 1}\delta\big(\log \frac{x}{n}\big)\Big)x^{-s-1}dx\quad $$

My question is: 
Is the first expression sufficient in the case of a variable $s$ with a non-vanishing imaginary part $\Im\{s\}\neq 0$ ?

It seems to me that the oscillatory behaviour introduced by the imaginary part of $s$ may allow, in the first expression, the exchange of the sum and the integral, and the convergence of the series, although it is not an absolute convergence for $\Re<1$. Is it correct?

Comment: What is $\delta$? And what is meant by "sufficient in the case $\Im{s} \not = 0$"?

Comment: You are right to recall me that we don't necessarily have the same writing conventions. I will precise it.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. Sometimes I forget things (not that I have a disease or something). For the first sight, this question looked an easy one about the Riemann zeta-function. But Now that it uses the Dirac-$\delta$ function, it is way over my head. For curiosity, let me ask. Your use of Dirac's function seems to be only of formality nature. Has there been any useful result in the literatures?

Comment: Indeed, I am just manipulating formally the object $\sum_m m^{-s}\delta(x-m)$ in a physicist spirit, because it can model the spectrum of a musical stationary sound. For this application, the Dirac delta could be replaced by an arbitrary thin pdf. You can find [here](http://xenharmonic.wikispaces.com/Mike%27s%20Zeta%20Function%20Working%20Page) and [there](http://xenharmonic.wikispaces.com/The+Riemann+Zeta+Function+and+Tuning)  some developments about its link to "Math&Music".

Comment: I read the link, and what you did with the sum $\sum_{n, d}$ is correct, I think. But physics part is just not understandable. It seems I didn't read about Dirac delta replaced by "arbitrary thin pdf".

Comment: By the way, I am not sure the real purpose of your project up there. But I for one think that attempting cooperative math research projects online will never lead to a success, unless you already have some respect and position and people who follow you.  I am not trying to discourage you, but that's just the way it is.

Comment: @Alexandre I recommend you take a look at $\zeta(s)=\frac{s}{s-1}+s\int_1^{\infty }(\lfloor x\rfloor-x)\,x^{-s-1}\,dx\,,\,\Re(s)>0\ \&\ s\ne 1$.